# Casting errors when using C++ function templates

Tags: c++, templates, casting, xcode5

This is my first post here. Feels kind of awkward actually ;-)

I'm struggling with C++ templates. I have a class `'textSettings"` that reads TXT files for value pairs, each on it's line, and puts them in std::map that uses std::string for both key and value.

Possible entrances in the text file could be for instance `GRID_SIZE 6`, so that the key of the map gets to be the string `"GRID_SIZE"` and the value is the string `"6"`.

In my program I want to use them as the type the value actually is: `int/float/bool/string`.

The program expects only to get these 4 types as input. I therefore use a templated function to find a certain value in the map through its key, and only instantiate it for these types.

In this function I'm checking the type using `std::tr1::is_same` to be able to parse the value correctly.

It fails at the else clause, where XCode complains, throwing three errors. It can't cast val to float or int or bool. The errors all look the same:

> /src/textSettings.cpp:82:17: Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type
>   'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')
>   /src/textSettings.cpp:82:17: Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type
>   'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')
>   /src/textSettings.cpp:82:17: Assigning to 'bool' from incompatible type
>   'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')

However all types complained about are already handled by the other `if` clauses. I really don't know how to deal with this. I'm still learning about C++ and templates, so I might be overlooking something obvious.
If I comment the line out, the program compiles and links perfectly. Obviously I can't parse values from the text file then...

I'm using XCode 5.1.1

**textSettings.h**

```
template<typename T>
bool findValue(const std::string& key, T& val);
```

**textSetting.cpp**

```
template<typename T>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, T& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        if (std::tr1::is_same<T, int>::value) {
            val = atoi(it->second.c_str());
        }
        else if (std::tr1::is_same<T, float>::value) {
            val = atof(it->second.c_str());
        }
        else if (std::tr1::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
            val = static_cast<bool>(atoi(it->second.c_str()));
        }
        else if (std::tr1::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
            val = it->second; // <- ERROR HERE
        }
        else {
            printf("Textsettings:: Error, type unknown!\n");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
template bool textSettings::findValue<int>(const std::string&, int&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<float>(const std::string&, float&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<bool>(const std::string&, bool&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<std::string>(const std::string&, std::string&);
```

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error, because, for instantiations other than `std::string`, you are assigning `it->second`, which is `std::string` to the variable referenced by `val` which is of non-assignable to string type (`float`, `int` or `bool`).

The fact that your condition `std::tr1::is_same<T, std::string>::value` will evaluate to `false` does not mean that you are not obliged to provide lexically correct code inside the conditional block.

This type of problem will be better solved by creating separate function overload for each needed type and use overloaded function invocation to automatically match the desired one:

```
bool ParseStr(const std::string& str, int& val) {
   val = atoi(str.c_str());
   return true;
}
bool ParseStr(const std::string& str, float& val) {
   val = atof(str.c_str());
   return true;
}
bool ParseStr(const std::string& str, bool& val) {
   val = static_cast<bool>(atoi(str.c_str()));
   return true;
}
bool ParseStr(const std::string& str, std::string& val) {
   val = str;
   return true;
}
template <typename T>
bool ParseStr(const std::string& str, T& val) {
   printf("Textsettings:: Error, type unknown!\n");
   return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, T& val) {
  std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
  it = data.find(key);
  if (it != data.end()) {
     return ParseStr(it->second, val);
  }
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

At each template instantiation there's only one `if` branch that is semantically correct and for which the compiler is able to generate proper instantiation code, while all the others remain just plain wrong.

Take a look at the following code, the error you're doing it is just plain the same:

```
{
    int a = 33; // Assume this code was into a template and 'int = T'
    if(std::is_same<decltype(a), int>::value)
        a = 44; // Okay
    else
        a = "hello"; // How can this compile?  
}
```

Since you're explicitly instantiating the templated function for all those types, the code is **actually being generated** and thus you're hitting errors.

## The solution

There are several solutions but a good one could be to specialize your function (remember: functions cannot be partially specialized)

```
template<typename T>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, T& val) {
    // type not recognized, assert or handle
    ...
    return false;
}

template<> // Specialized for int
bool textSettings::findValue<int>(const std::string &key, int& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        val = atoi(it->second.c_str());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// all the others..

template bool textSettings::findValue<int>(const std::string&, int&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<float>(const std::string&, float&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<bool>(const std::string&, bool&);
template bool textSettings::findValue<std::string>(const std::string&, std::string&);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mis-understood the concept of type traits usage. The type traits are evaluated as a constant expression during compile time and is replaced by a constant value that is evaluated during runtime. So in your example for `T=int`, the following is the equivalent template instance code being evaluated

```
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, int& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        if (true) {
            val = atoi(it->second.c_str());
        }
        else if (false) {
            val = atof(it->second.c_str());
        }
        else if (false) {
            val = static_cast<bool>(atoi(it->second.c_str()));
        }
        else if (false) {
            val = it->second; // <- ERROR HERE
        }
        else {
            printf("Textsettings:: Error, type unknown!\n");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the line being error-ed out is still being compiled but per se' in the context of type `int`, its an invalid expression where a string is being assigned to an integer.

type-traits may be helpful during template evaluation, but in this particular case, template specialization is best to use for selection of code based on type.

```
template<typename T>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, T& val) {
    printf("Textsettings:: Error, type unknown!\n");
    return false;
}

template<>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, std::string& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        val = it->second; // <- ERROR HERE
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, int& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        val = atoi(it->second.c_str());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, float& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        val = atof(it->second.c_str());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<>
bool textSettings::findValue(const std::string &key, bool& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end()) {
        val = static_cast<bool>(atoi(it->second.c_str()));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use solution based on so-called **tag-dispatching**. The most popular example is implementing std::advance. Here is an [example](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching).
The problem in your code that compiler will try to instantiate your function for any given type `T`. Imagine that you are calling function with `T = int`. Then replace all `T` with `int`. Will your function compile ? No, because `val` will be `int` and you will try to assign `std::string` to `int` and there is no implicit conversion.

Here is your [code live](http://rextester.com/GRSU46604):
All you need is next trick (see tag-dispatching link below):

```
bool dispatcher(const std::string& str, int& val) {
    val = atoi(str.c_str());
    return true;
}

bool dispatcher(const std::string& str, float& val) {
    val = atof(str.c_str());
    return true;
}

bool dispatcher(const std::string& str, bool& val) {
    val = static_cast<bool>(atoi(str.c_str()));
    return true;
}

bool dispatcher(const std::string& str, std::string& val) {
    val = str;
    return true;
}

bool dispatcher(const std::string& str, ...) {
    printf("Textsettings:: Error, type unknown!\n");
    return false;
}


template<typename T>
bool findValue(const std::string &key, T& val) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    it = data.find(key);
    if (it != data.end())
        return dispatcher(it->second, val);
    return false;
}
```